# Cutting a part of window.open in python (web scraping)

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup, and right now I am getting this result:

```
window.open('../qwerty/abcde_fgh.php?uid=123a&company=companyname&name=hisname','','width=100,height=100,scrollbars=yes,resize=yes')
```

I want to get the value of company and name(which is companyname and hisname), like this:

```
name
hisname
```

Is there any way that I can only get the value of company and name?

Comment: It returns empty list, the original value of company and name is in Korean letter, would it be a problem?

Comment: window.open('../qwerty/abcde_fgh.php?uid=123a&company=제주회사이름&name=그분성함','','width=100,height=100,scrollbars=yes,resize=yes')

Comment: Sorry, seems like I made a mistake, it works for me too! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
company=(?P<company>.*?)&name=(?P<name>.*)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`company=`** - Matches `company=` literally.
- **`(?P<company>.*?)`** - Represents named capturing group matching everything before `&` **lazily.**
- **`(?P<name>.*)`** - Represents another named-capturing group(in case you want to refer them by name) matching everything after `name=` **greedily.**

[image]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/vr67zP/1/)

---

**Sample Implementation in python:**

```
import re
string = "../qwerty/abcde_fgh.php?uid=123a&company=제주회사이름&name=그분성함"
print(re.findall(r"\bcompany\b=(?P<company>.*?)&name=(?P<name>.*)", string))
```

You can find the sample run of the above code in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/BJ0OUg6CI)